# What network protocols are used to connect to the SWIFT network?

Tags: swift-mt

I understand that [SWIFT messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIFT_message_types) over the SWIFT network are used to exchange financial information between financial institutions.

What network protocols do banking applications use to connect to and send the messages on the SWIFT network?

Is it SWIFT Message over SOAP&HTTPS over TCP/IP? Is it SWIFT Messages in a file over SFTP over TCP/IP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The messages themselves are just text, and can flow over various transports.

The SWIFT network itself is [IP based (formerly X.25)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_for_Worldwide_Interbank_Financial_Telecommunication).  However, most applications interact via some intermediary, e.g. [SIL](https://www.swift.com/our-solutions/interfaces-and-integration/swift-integration-layer-sil_), that lets you talk MQ, files, or whatever.

Comment: Adding to this answer, most Bank has a SWIFT Alliance Access box on their premises with back-office applications connected via file system or MQ. Smaller financial institutions may have the SWIFT Lite solution, wich also supports file system integration. Some vendors provide solutions implementing the SNL protocol, thus connecting directly to a SWIFT Alliance gateway box on the institution premises. Finally, there are also service bureaus, offering SWIFT connectivity to many financial customers.